Cohomology of representation varieties and the Hochschild cohomology
Let $k$ be a field, $A$ a $k$-algebra, and $V$ a $k$-vector space. Then we can consider the representation varieties of $A$ on $V$: $\mathrm{Hom}_{k\textrm{-alg}}(A, \mathfrak{gl}(V))$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{k\textrm{-alg}}(A, \mathfrak{gl}(V))//\mathrm{GL}(V)$.
Question: How are the (co)homology of these spaces computed? Especially, are they related to the Hochschild/cyclic (co)homology of $A$?
Some things I want to say:

Of course, these varieties depend on (the dimension of) $V$, so the stable (co)homology would be the most that we might recover from $A$ itself. We may assume $k$ to be algebraically closed and/or of char. 0, and $A$ to be finitely presented.
I'm mainly interested in low-dimensional cases, e.g., various path algebras of a quiver and $k\pi_1(M)$ for some surface $M$. If $M$ is a closed surface, there are similar questions on MO (like this) but they are pretty old. I'll be glad if I'm informed about recent progress (if any) regarding this topic.

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated.
